# How to Change the context path of CookieLocaleResolver?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

`org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver`sets the context path as /.I want to change it from / to /app1 so that no other app in the same directory can see it.How to do this?

Comment: Have you taken the time to look at [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html) especially the inherited methods?

Comment: yes,have already done this   
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" >
    <property name="cookieMaxAge"><value>-1</value></property>
    <property name="cookiePath" value="pankaj" />
    
  </bean>
but now cookie is not coming at all.

Comment: The path has to match your applications path if it doesn't you will not see it. also a path starts with a / generally.